# Computing the local orbital frame vector directions and angles of gyroscope direction in the satellite

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, orbit, frames

In the context of the study of a cubesat (little satellite), I am asked to define the local orbital frame and compute the local orbital frame vector directions as a function of time (`I have to use a little scritpt Matlab or Python`) and get the coordinates of a gyroscop in the satellite.

Here the context :

[image: Attitude for a cubesat]

For the part 2.1, I have found the following figures for geocentric inertial reference frame :

[image]

and local orbit frame :

[image]

I think that, for part 2.1, vector directions of local orbital frame are simply the directions of curvilinear coordinates for an ellipse ($\vec{e_{r}}$ and $\vec{e_{\theta}}$ vectors for polar coordinates and $\vec{e_{z}}$ orthogonal to $\vec{e_{r}}$ and $\vec{e_{\theta}}$), so an elliptic trajectory with these 3 basis vectors would be enough : is it correct ?

Now what about the part 2.2 "Kinematics", anyone could give some advices ?

Regards

Comment: In addition to the bounty, a good way to attract the most interest in helping, you can consider adding any work you have done so far. Even if you know there may be some errors, it's better to show what you have tried. The more effort you show, possibly the more people will be interested in helping, and certainly the more they will understand what specific help would be the best. Right now this is so open ended people may not know what it is you do, or do not already understand.